# how do I reference my public class property, Event.Day, in my other class' method?

Tags: c#

I am trying to reference my public class property in other class' method but I must not be doing it properly. Is there anyone that can help? It is the ExtractData(**Event special.Day**) part.

```
public static List<Event> ExtractData(Event special.Day)
{
   int intChosenDay = special.Day;  

    StreamReader textIn =
    new StreamReader(
    new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read));

     //create the list
     List<Event> events = new List<Event>();



     string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

     for (int index = 4; index < lines.Length; index += 5)
     {
        Event special = new Event();
        special.Day = Convert.ToInt32(lines[index - 4]);
        special.Time = (lines[index - 3]);
        special.Price = Convert.ToDouble(lines[index - 2]);
        special.StrEvent = lines[index - 1];
        special.Description = lines[index];
        events.Add(special);
     }

     textIn.Close();

     return events;

}
```

Comment: what's use of that parameter in the method?

Comment: @LolCoder Good question...I want to say..if parameter(int Day) is equal to any one of special.Day, give me the lines[0], lines[1], lines[2], lines[3], and lines[4] of that same loop. I am so confused right now...ughhh

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass parameter `Day` to the method then you should specify its type, not the event Type. Like:

```
public static List<Event> ExtractData(int Day)
{
 //....your code
}
```

(If Day is `int` type, then specify `int`, otherwise specify the type accordingly.

Later you can call it like:

```
Events event = new Event();
var list = ExtractData(event.Day);
```

Since `ExtractData` is a static method, and if you are calling it from outside of the class you have to call it with the class name like:

```
var list = Event.ExtractData(event.Day); //if the class name is Event
```

Comment: I am trying to get the special.Day(example: 21) and store it to a variable. Could I do public static List<Event> ExtractData(int Day) { int Day = special.Day ......} How would I accomplish that?

Comment: @Jae,  method signature would be like you described in the comment. You call should be `ExtractData(special.Day);`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a member-property in the method definition, you can only define the function arguments passed in (via a "[type] [variable-name]" format).

One way to achieve what you're trying to do is inside your method you can access the property and either directly use it or store it to another variable:

```
public static List<Event> ExtractData(Event theEvent) {
    int day = theEvent.Day;
    // ...
```

Comment: How would I go about storing the special.Day number(s) stored into an "int Day" if I were to change my method to public static List<Event> ExtractData(int Day) {.......} ?

Comment: @Jae I'm not sure I follow... if your method is `ExtractData(int Day)`, you would call it with `ExtractData(special.Day)` and then inside the method you would just use the `Day` variable... if I understand your question

Comment: Well...on my main form I have another method that is supposed to call EventDB.ExtractData(mvwDate.SelectionStart). mvwDate.SelectionStart is the MonthCaldendar day that the user clicks on. I'm trying to connect the user's clicked day and call the ExtractData method if that makes any sesne...